# Update warning when shutting down or restarting Linux-Deepin

Tags: linux, deepin

I recently installed Linux Deepin, I used it before without any problems, it is in perfect condition, the only problem is that every time I restart or shut down the system, this warning message appears, "Unattended Upgrades Shutdown -Stop ongoing upgrades or perform upgrades before shutdown

The programs are preventing the computer from reboot, and forcing reboot may cause data loss. To close the program, click Cancel, and then close the program."

As shown in the photo, I don't know what to do, every time I turn off normally but I wanted to know if there is any way to remove this warning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What photo? Clearly there's some updates going on - unattended upgrades handle mainly security upgrades, so, probably important that you let them finish

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an update/upgrade was underway and then never finished.

I ran into this issue with an Ubuntu Desktop, started doing the upgrade with the GUI, left for a bit came back and the system was hung. I had to SSH into the box and reboot it.

After that I used the CLI to restart the updates, I got a warning about unfinished updates with the command needed to finish the process.

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Seeing how Deepin is Debian try doing the apt-get update; apt-get upgrade and see if gives you a warning about updates not being installed.

You may be able to get away with one of the following commands to fix it.

```
apt-get -f install

dpkg --configure -a

dpkg-reconfigure -a
```